# Where does XAML get his version information from?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reference, version

I'm working on a XAML-based C# WPF application, having a file "Utilities.dll" as a reference. The properties of that DLL file mentions "1.0.0.0" as the version and "v4.0.30319" as the runtime version.
This is confirmed in the "*.csproj" file:

```
<Reference Include="Utilities,
           Version=1.0.0.0,
           Culture=neutral,
           processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

The XAML contains the following:

- In the list of namespaces, there is the following:

  ```
  xmlns:zoomcontrol="clr-namespace:Utilities.ZoomControl;assembly=Utilities"
  ```
- Within the definition of the grid, the Zoomcontrol is used:

  ```
  <zoomcontrol:ZoomControl   MaxZoomDelta="1.1" >
  ```

I'm facing following error message:

```
XDG00003 : Could not load type 'Utilities.ZoomControl.ZoomControl' from assembly
  'Utilities, Version=3.1.1.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'.
```

All "Utilities.DLL" files I have (in programming and in runtime environment), have version "1.0.0.0", I don't have any "3.1.1.4" version of that file.

Where is the mentioned error message coming from, and why is it saying that I need version "3.1.1.4", where does Visual Studio get that version number from?

ILSpy screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you that **you do, in fact** have a `3.1.1.4` version of `Utilities.dll` but that your `<Reference>` is **incorrectly** restricted to `Version=1.0.0.0`.

Comment: @Dai: how do you mean that? When I use Windows Explorer, click-right on the DLL and ask the details, both file version and product version are equal to "1.0.0.0". So where can I find out that "3.1.1.4" version number? (This is true for the DLLs both in runtime environment and programming environment)

Comment: The version number displayed in File Properties in Explorer is the Win32 PE `VERSION` resource - it is not the same thing as the .NET assembly version - to get that you need to use a tool like ILSpy or ILDasm - or use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName().Version`

Comment: I don't have those tools, but I have Jetbrains DotPeek, which also is a decompiler. Where should I look for that version number? it is called "Utilities (1.0.0.0, msil, .Net Framework v4.6.1)"

Comment: JetBrains DotPeek shows Metadata, Headers, CLI (Cor20) header, which contains MajorRuntimeVersion 0x0002 and MinorRuntimeVersion 0x0005.

Comment: ILSpy shows similar information.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you see in ILSpy to your question-post. **Exactly** where on your disk is the `Utilities.dll` file you loaded into ILSpy and how are you certain that's the same physical file on-disk that your project is loading at runtime? (Is it the same as what's in your `bin\net48\Debug` directory?

Comment: @Dai: I added the screenshot.

Comment: Where are you seeing the "Could not load type 'Utilities.ZoomControl.ZoomControl' from assembly 'Utilities, Version=3.1.1.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'." error? That sounds like a WPF Designer error...

Comment: @Dai: it is a WPF Designer error indeed: I see that error message in the "Error List". The reason for this question is that I almost see nothing of my form., When I remove the ZoomControl from the XAML, the entire form becomes visible, and I believe that, once the error message is solved I will be capable of seeing my form in the designer.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the DLL you're using appears to be part of Visual Studio - so that's going to mess with how the designer works.

Comment: @Dai: Ok, thanks, I'll see about the possibility to rename or even remove that DLL.